# Using Recursion to Convert Number to Other Number Bases

Tags: java, recursion

> assume num >=0, base is between 2 and 10;
> convert(13, 2) returns "1101"

Here is my code so far i get StackOverFlow error

```
public String convert(int num, int base) { 
  if (num < 0 || base < 2 && base >10) {
    return""; 
  }
  return convert(num / base, base) + (num % base);  
}
```

Comment: You should replace `num < 0` with `num <= 0`.  But `convert(0, 2)` returns empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to what @saka1029 said about `num < 0` needing to be `num <= 0` and `return "";` needing some attention when `num=0`, you have `&& base > 10` rather than `|| base > 10`. You're essentially saying "if our number is negative (**impossible given that the starting num is at least 0**) or the base is less than two AND greater than 10 (***also* impossible, a number cannot be less than two and greater than 10**), then return an empty String.

You're getting a StackOverflow error because your recursive function is an infinite loop. `num` cannot be less than 0 and `base` cannot be both less than two and greater than ten at the same time.